# Idea cannot find my tables in String with Postgresql language injection

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

I have been using Language Injection in Java code with Intellij Idea for years.  It is nice because I can CTRL+Click from SQL types in my string in my Java to the schema in the data sources tab.

Recently I had to change all of our SQL queries to not hard code a schema name.  Everything runs fine but Intellij thinks all of my tables do not exist inside my Postgresql Language strings.

In the SQL console in IDEA I fixed this by setting the search path.  However I do not see where I can set the search path of injected strings in my Java.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: It appears If I change my schema name to "public" it works.  But what if I want a different schema name?

Answer (score 1):

Press CTRL+SHIFT+A -> find 'Attach session' action -> select target PG data source -> you can use already opened console session or create a new one, then you will be able to edit search path.

Comment: This doesnt work.  Is there a different keymapping on MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly for that case IDEA has "SQL Resolution Scopes" mapping. There you can define mapping between files, data sources and expected "search path"[image]